# Social choice theory, preference aggregation data sets

Tags: boolean-functions, gt.game-theory, combinatorics, social-sciences

I do computational research on preference aggregation. I am quite interested in Kemeny Optimal Aggregation. However I do not find much useful data for preference aggregation in context of social science where I can test my concepts and algorithms. I am not merely interested in meta-search stuffs. I am looking for some pure committee decision, voting type of social data. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think there should be some crowdsourcing research along these lines. E.g., you ask a group of workers to provide answers to a task and use a voting rule to aggregate their responses. I don't know a lot about it but maybe if you want to say more specifically what you'd like to do with the data someone will have suggestions on where to find it (or how to generate it...).

Comment: I have some rank aggregation algorithms to test. For example, say there is a set candidates $A,B,C,D$ now 100 voters are asked to rank them. I need this kind of multiple ranked lists.

Comment: I guess a big question is whether you want some "ground truth" to compare against, e.g. there is a "correct" underlying ranking and you want to see how well different voting rules do compared to that. Or maybe you don't need the data to have an underlying true ranking.

Comment: In IJCAI 2013, there was a talk about preflib.org ; a library for preference data. Have you checked it?

Comment: Thanks @seteropere a lot for the link.. I did not check that before. This will serve my purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. @usul thanks for your reply.. Actually I am designing my own social choice function and I want to see how well that function reflect the true general will.

Comment: The Microsoft LETOR (Learning to rank) dataset is widely used as a benchmark to compare algorithms http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/beijing/projects/letor/